# Delta time string to datetime object

Tags: python, datetime

Given a string that looks like `"Hours:5 Minutes:34 Seconds:28"` or `"Minutes:34 Seconds:28"`, is there any pythonic way to convert it to a `datetime` object? I do not want to use a regex if there's an easier way.

Comment: Why do You have `Minutes` and `Seconds` two times?

Comment: No, "Hours:5 Minutes:34 Seconds:28", "Minutes:34 Seconds:28", "Seconds:28". This is three example of input string with date, String always consist Secounds and if neede consist Minutes, Houers, Days...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. You can do it like this:

```
import time

datetime_string = "Hours:5 Minutes:34 Seconds:28"
if "Hours" in datetime_string:
    datetime_object = time.strptime(datetime_string, "Hours:%H Minutes:%M Seconds:%S")
elif "Minutes" in datetime_string:
    datetime_object = time.strptime(datetime_string, "Minutes:%M Seconds:%S")
else:
    datetime_object = time.strptime(datetime_string, "Seconds:%S")
```

**Note**: When You create datetime object, values that You do not provide will be filled with default values.So, in case `datetime_string` contains only seconds, hours and minutes will be set to `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) to convert string into `datetime` object as:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> date_object = datetime.strptime('Hours:5 Minutes:34 Seconds:28', 'Hours:%H Minutes:%M Seconds:%S')
>>> date_object
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 5, 34, 28)
#                             ^   ^   ^
#                           Hour Min  Seconds
```

Since you do not have date in the string, it will keep the default date of `1 Jan 1990`. I think what you need is [`datetime.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.time) which return `time` object with same hour, minute, second and microsecond as in you `datetime` object. ([tzinfo](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.tzinfo) is `None`). For example:

```
>>> date_object.time()
datetime.time(5, 34, 28)
#             ^   ^   ^
#          Hour  Min  Seconds
```

where `date_object` is of `datetime` type created earlier.